# Как получить из TextBox выделенный мышью текст и менять его?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть обычное приложение `windowsForms` с `TextBox`, `ComboBox` и `NumericUpDown` элементами. Простой текстовый редактор. Я могу при изменении значения в одном из элементов менять шрифт во всем текстовом поле, например, меняю размер шрифта так:

```
private void sizeUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        textBox.Font = new Font(textBox.Font.FontFamily, (int)sizeUpDown.Value);
}
```

и размер меняется во всем текстовом поле. Как можно поменять выделенный мышью текст?

Comment: Привет. Попробуй SelectexText. `textBox1.SelectedText`....

Comment: Имхо SelectedText не поможет. Для форматирования части текста вместо TextBox можно использовать RichTextBox. Например, задать, `richTextBox1.SelectionFont`.